# Length of _QueryIterator

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, gql

I'm trying to get the length of the result of the following query:

`matchingTitles = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Post WHERE title=:1",title).run()`

I tried doing this:

`if(len(matchingTitles)>0):`

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type '_QueryIterator' has no len()
```

I've been searching all over for the `_QueryIterator`object docs, but can't seem to find any. I instead just iterated over it and incremented a number "for each" item in the set. Wondering if there was a better way...

Thanks!

**EDIT**

There's a better way to do this. Instead of running and then counting, you can simply do:

`matchingTitles = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Post WHERE title=:1",title).count()`

and it returns the number of entities.

Comment: have you tried `matchingTitles.count()`? Not familiar with Google Query, but if this object is in fact a real iterator, and not just fancy-named - you will not be able to find out its length, by design.

Comment: @Lawrence, unfortunately `count` is not an attribute.

Comment: Then as I said, you can not get the length of an iterator until you iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

This can take a lot of memory, but you could use itertools.tee:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this question actually looking for the length of a _QueryIterator, you can try:

```
len(list(matchingTitles)) # This will load all the results into memory before counting.
# OR
sum([1 for _ in matchingTitles])
```

As mentioned though - it's usually better / faster / cheaper to use the database's count functionality than loading all the records and iterating over them. There may be a reason you can't use that - in which case those two options are available.